# Jenkins Plug-in - Post-build Step - with many config options

Tags: java, json, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I'm currently working on a Jenkins plug-in which is a post-build step (extends hudson.tasks.Builder). I make use of both global.jelly & config.jelly within the matching resources directory structure.

Up to now, for each field I've been using the following...

- `@DataBoundConstructor` with a parameter for each field in my config
- `private final` field for each field in my config
- Custom getter for each field in my config

I have lots of things to configure, I feel there must be some easier way, to do with the JSON it uses in the background, which I can traverse myself much more cleanly?

How is the data actually persisted, as my current understanding is that it uses the getter's populate the value and how it actually stores the values I'm not sure?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is the only way I know of to configure your builder. Jenkins persists all your configurations in your job's config.xml file.

Comment: so it definitely needs the getters to then load those values out of the config.xml? Can that config file be inspected manually? ie is it accessible from code?

Comment: yes you definitely need the getters for the persistence logic to work. I am not sure if you can access the xml, but you should be able to access those arguments from your the Project instance of that job in your code.